# paintComponent not called when adding custom JComponent

Tags: java, swing, awt

Why is `paintComponent(Graphics)` not called when adding a custom JComponent?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint Component Example");

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 750));
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.add(new CustomComponent());
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class CustomComponent extends JComponent {

    public CustomComponent() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

I know there is no reason for creating a custom component in this instance of but it is an extremely simplified version of another issue I can't figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new CustomComponent());
```

The default layout manager of a `JPanel` is a `FlowLayout`. A `FlowLayout` will respect the preferred size of any component added to it. By default the preferred size of a `JComponent` is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint so the paintComponent() method never gets called.

Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of your `CustomComponent` class to return the preferred size of your component.

Also, don't forget to invoke `super.paintComponent(...)` at the start of the method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.